# Using jar in asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jar

I have a problem I want to use jar in asp.net project.

My code:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Request.MapPath("/");

        process1.StartInfo.FileName = Request.MapPath("kokBul.jar");

        process1.Start();
```

Error:

a java exception has occurred

please help

Thanks..

Comment: You *really* shouldn't give your web processes the ability to run applications. It's a potential security issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Error:
>
> a java exception has occurred

indicates there is an error in the JAR file try opening the jar outside the project if it opens outside the project there must be an error in the way it is called

Edit 1 This article may help you [Execute jar in asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1162909.aspx/1)

Edit 2 try deleting the `Class-path:` line out of the `Meta-inf` `MANIFEST.MF` file and try again and if that doesn't work delete the entire meta-inf file

Hope this helps

Comment: @SelimÖzdem - Run the jar from the location your trying to run it from I guarantee it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

ok.

I solved the problem of.

I forgot to add the jar libraries used in

My Code:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Request.MapPath("/");

    process1.StartInfo.FileName = Request.MapPath("kokBul.jar");

    process1.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a JAR file directly in .Net.

It must be converted into a DLL, for which you can use IKVM.NET.

You can run:

> run ikvmc -target:library mylib.jar

to create mylib.dll.

[IKVM: Use Java libraries in your .Net apps](http://www.ikvm.net/uses.html#Use+Java+libraries+in+your+.NET+applications)

Comment: That's not what he's asking. Read the question -- he wants to execute a .jar using the Java runtime.

Comment: thank you Nathan, I applied it said.
my problem link: www.selimozdem.com/warning.PNG

Comment: Thanks @Nathan it worked for me. I believe in the solution. Main purpose of this question is to use all java functions in C#. I don't know why your reply is down-voted. If I could I can give 100 up-votes. I followed the steps and it worked! . Thanks again. This is the best solution. :)